# AWS- Maintain Code across multiple EC2 instances behind an ELB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I want to have same code across my all multiple instances behind an ELB. 
Currently I use :

I use `git pull origin master` on every instances by SSH logging in.

Is there any other way to do so on all instances in a single time/click?

Alternatives *i know please don't suggest* : 
Using s3 sync *its a bit vague*
And Using Cron jobs but it will run continuously but i want it pull code at manual times when i want.

Any suggestions are appreciated. :)

Comment: From your code canxwe assume you want to updare some files from a repository without redeploying  or restarting the servers?

Comment: yeah. i don't want to restart or reboot just update the code.
I do have found something by using GIT HOOKS but still fully not understood how i could use them.

Comment: AWS CodeDeploy is a deployment service that automates application deployments to Amazon EC2 instances, on-premises instances, or serverless Lambda functions.

Comment: Okay John sure, i will check it out. :)

Comment: As well cf-init from Cloudformation could update files or execute a command on update. However I'd stick to AWS CodeDeploy, that's better option